# React Native Android: how to resolve this build error with compileSdkVersion?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, gradle

I'm trying to build my React Native app after adding the [react-native-vision-camera](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera) library, and I get the following build error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (30) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
        Dependency: androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha27.
```

My `android/build.gradle` includes the following:

```
buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 31
targetSdkVersion = 31
```

My understanding from the error is that my `compileSdkVersion` isn't high enough, and it's saying that it's 29, but in `build.gradle` I have it at 31.

How can I address this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` with the same version of the `buildToolsVersion`

try:

```
buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 30
targetSdkVersion = 30
```

or:

```
buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 31
targetSdkVersion = 31
```